# Remove "thaithai" when using babel for Thai script

Tags: babel

I am working on a multilingual document using `babel`. The main language is English and there are short passages in languages with other scripts. When I try to include Thai using `\foreignlanguage`, "thaithai" appears right before the actual text in Thai (but only the first time). What is causing this and how can it be removed?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{thai}
\babelfont[thai]{rm}{Garuda}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{thai}{ภาษาไทย}

\foreignlanguage{thai}{ภาษาไทย}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when was it last updated? The reason I ask is that I experience no issues at all when I compile your sample code on a computer on which I've installed MacTeX2023 (with all updates applied).

Comment: I use Overleaf.

Comment: Try using LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX to compile your test document on Overleaf.

Comment: Thank you, that does solve the issue. However, I use XeLaTeX when using a thesis template, so I would appreciate a solution with XeLaTeX too.

Comment: It seems there is a bug. Here is a quick workaround: `\AddBabelHook[thai]{babel-ensure}{patterns}{}`.

Comment: @user242399 Bug found. I’ll fix it in the next release, in 3-4 days.